# Github GraphQL Error: A query attribute must be specified and must be a string

Tags: github, graphql

I have two different queries.

The first is in a private repo:

```
const query = `{
  repository(
    owner: "PrivateOrg"
    name: "privateRepoName"
  ) {
    name
    forkCount
    forks(
      first: 11
      orderBy: { field: NAME, direction: DESC }
    ) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

The second is in a public repo. I tested it on [Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) before putting it in my nodeJS app - **it works on explorer**:

```
const querytwo = `{
  repository(
    owner: "mongodb"
    name: "docs-bi-connector"
  ) {
    name
    forkCount
    forks(
      first: 27
      orderBy: { field: NAME, direction: DESC }
    ) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

The fetch for both look identical except the queries:

```
  fetch('https://api.github.com/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({query}),
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
}).then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => console.log(body))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
  console.log("\n\n\n");

    fetch('https://api.github.com/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({querytwo}),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    }).then(res => res.text())
      .then(body => console.log(body))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
    console.log("\n\n\n");
```

The first query returns:

```
{"data":{"repository":{"name":"mms-docs","forkCount":26,"forks":{"totalCount":8,"nodes":[{"name":"mms-docs"},{"name":"mms-docs"},{"name":"mms-docs"},{"name":"mms-docs"},{"name":"mms-docs"},{"name":"mms-docs"},{"name":"mms-docs"},{"name":"mms-docs"}]}}}}
```

**But the second query returns an error:**

```
{"errors":[{"message":"A query attribute must be specified and must be a string."}]}
```

Why would that be?

I've tried changing the second, faulty query to what I've seen in curl calls:

```
const querytwo = `query: {
      repository(
        owner: "mongodb"
        name: "docs-bi-connector"
      ) {
        name
        forkCount
        forks(
          first: 27
          orderBy: { field: NAME, direction: DESC }
        ) {
          totalCount
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }`;
```

But I get the same error

Answer (score 3):

Shorthand object notation mistake

```
JSON.stringify({query})
```

is shorthand for `JSON.stringify({query: query})`

which becomes

```
{
query: 
 {
      repository(
        owner: "PrivateOrg"
        name: "privateRepoName"
      ) {
        name
        forkCount
        forks(
          first: 11
          orderBy: { field: NAME, direction: DESC }
        ) {
          totalCount
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }`
```

`JSON.stringify({querytwo})` is shorthand for `JSON.stringify({querytwo: querytwo})`

```
{
querytwo: 
 {
      repository(
        owner: "PrivateOrg"
        name: "privateRepoName"
      ) {
        name
        forkCount
        forks(
          first: 11
          orderBy: { field: NAME, direction: DESC }
        ) {
          totalCount
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }`
```

Hence why GraphQL couldn't find a `query` - it found a `queryTwo`